# CakePHP - Adding Form Validation based on Database Fields

Tags: regex, forms, validation, cakephp-2.0

I need to validate shipping information entered when goods are dispatched. (I am having a nightmare using Cake!)

Each shipping company has a different format for their tracking references.  I have written some regex to validate, and these are stored in my database.

All the validation for CakePHP happens in the model so I cannot use `$this` to retrieve the correct regex.

The regex is available in the view; is there anyway to use this to validate before the form  is submitted?

I am currently sending the data through an ajax call

Controller

```
    public function editTracking() {
    $this->autoRender = false;

    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        if($this->GoodsOutNote->save($this->request->data['GoodsOutNote'])){
            $this->GoodsOutNote->save($this->request->data['GoodsOutNote']);
            print_r($this->request->data['GoodsOutNote']['tracking_details']);
        }else{
            print_r($errors = $this->GoodsOutNote->validationErrors);
        }

    }
}
```

View

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('GoodsOutNote',array(
'action'=>'editTracking','default' => false)); ?>
<fieldset>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('id',array(
        'default'=>$goodsOutNote['GoodsOutNote']['id']));

    echo $this->Form->input('tracking_details',array(
        'default'=>$goodsOutNote['GoodsOutNote']['tracking_details']));
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));

$data = $this->Js->get('#GoodsOutNoteEditTrackingForm')->serializeForm(array(
'isForm' => true, 'inline' => true));

$this->Js->get('#GoodsOutNoteEditTrackingForm')->event('submit',
$this->Js->request(
array('action' => 'editTracking', 'controller' => 'goods_out_notes'),
    array(
        'update' => '#tracking_details,#GoodsOutNoteTrackingDetails',
        'data' => $data,
        'async' => true,    
        'dataExpression'=>true,
        'method' => 'PUT'
    )
  )
);
 echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); 
?>
```

In the view, I can use `$goodsOutNote['ShippingMethod']['valid_regex']` to access the correct format but I am lost as to how I can pass this to the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this using the following approach.

In my controller, I retrieve the full record that I am about to edit.  I can then validate the input using `preg_match()`.  I would really appreciate any comments on this - is there a better approach?

```
public function editTracking() {
    $this->autoRender = false;

    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {

        $id = $this->request->data['GoodsOutNote']['id'];
        $options = array('conditions' => array('GoodsOutNote.' . $this->GoodsOutNote->primaryKey => $id));
        $goodsOutNote = $this->GoodsOutNote->find('first', $options);

        $trackingRef = $this->request->data['GoodsOutNote']['tracking_details'];
        $regex = "/".$goodsOutNote['ShippingMethod']['valid_regex']."/";

        if(preg_match($trackingRef,$regex)){
            if($this->GoodsOutNote->save($this->request->data['GoodsOutNote'])){
                $this->GoodsOutNote->save($this->request->data['GoodsOutNote']);
            print_r($trackingRef);
            }
            else{
            print_r($errors = $this->GoodsOutNote->validationErrors);
            }
        }
        else {
            print_r($errors = $trackingRef.'is not valid');
        }

    }
}
```